# onFocusChange is not getting called when launching an activity above android version 8

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I'm having `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` inside `TextInputLayout` in my activity and added `setOnFocusChangeListener` for the `editText`. When ever the activity is opened its automatically called `onFocusChange` for the top first `editText` till android version 8. But when i was running it in android 9 and above `onFocusChange` for the top first editText is not getting called. Can you please suggest an idea to fix it.

Below is my activity,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EIScanEditTextView edtUserName, passwordEdt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        passwordEdt = (EIScanEditTextView) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
        edtUserName = (EIScanEditTextView) findViewById(R.id.edt_user_name);
        edtUserName.setTransformationMethod(new AllCapTransformationMethod());
        passwordEdt.setTransformationMethod(new AllCapTransformationMethod());
        edtUserName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new GenericTextWatcher(edtUserName));
        passwordEdt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new GenericTextWatcher(passwordEdt));
    }

    private class GenericTextWatcher implements View.OnFocusChangeListener {

        private final View view;

        private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.edt_user_name:
                    String mCurrentFocus;
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        mCurrentFocus = Constants.InputFilePattern.KEY_OH;
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.edt_password:
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        mCurrentFocus = Constants.InputFilePattern.KEY_PO;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And my layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/control_padding_m"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.eiscanning.login.MainActivity">

    <com.example.eiscanning.ui.ValidatedTextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/control_padding_xs">

        <com.example.eiscanning.ui.EIScanEditTextView
            android:id="@+id/edt_user_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:fontName="Roboto-Regular.ttf" />

    </com.example.eiscanning.ui.ValidatedTextInputLayout >

    <com.example.eiscanning.ui.ValidatedTextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/control_padding_xs"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.example.eiscanning.ui.EIScanEditTextView
            android:id="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:fontName="Roboto-Regular.ttf" />

    </com.example.eiscanning.ui.ValidatedTextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And i'm using below dependencies,

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".login.MainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```